# Gmail API Request Excel VBA PHP

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using Excel VBA to get a user's oAuth2 token for the mail.google.com scope for a native application. It works fine so I have the the user's Access Token (it refreshes if it expires) and I have the user's email address. I was using Zend SMTP to send the emails but found out there are limits to bulk sending emails this way (currently my account is locked out due to going over quota while trying to figure this out over the weekend). My client may send 2,000 emails at once and locking themselves out of their Gmail account for 24 hours is unacceptable. I think using the Gmail REST API will work, as it has higher quotas, but not finding any detailed PHP examples of how to create and send an HTML email via an HTTP request.

I know I have to create the MIME email and think I can figure that out (using this thread stackoverflow.com/questions/24940984/send-email-using-gmail-api-and-google-api-php-client) or from the Zend emails I was successfully creating. My question is what PHP code do I use to create and send the email?

The Google Dev examples all reference `/userId/` (from developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) but not sure where to get that if I just have the users token and their email address.

I assume it's something like this:

```
<?php
require 'GoogleAPI/src/Google/autoload.php';
extract($_POST); // use to get my client token, client's email address, the email to, cc, bcc, subject, body, etc.

//<Build the email $mime message here>

$m = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$data = base64_encode($mime);
$data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data); // url safe
$m->setRaw($data);
$service->users_messages->send('me', $m);
?>
```

I don't know where to put the user's token. I know 'me' is the person that is authenticated.

I'm open to using an HTTP request as well, something like https://mywebsite.com/sendgmail.php?token=[UsersToken]&UserEmail=joe@test.com&ToEmail=toperson@xyz.com&Subject=HI&Body=Thanks for your help instead of the post method.

Just not sure how to implement that either.

I'm self taught PHP and VBA and new to the google api world so please forgive me if this is easy. I'm also looking into boxspring but trying to use the native APIs and PHP first.

EDIT:
So I've tried this using the examples but getting an error that my token is not in proper JSON format. I just want to send the token as a string. If I can't is there a way to make the string into JSON so oauth2 will accept it?:

```
<?php
require 'GoogleAPI/src/Google/autoload.php';

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAccessToken('ya29.hwFcwk2M73vaPwNObeuwizHGjXT2y6UsAFEcDIvRAoWTM28gu2pJeK4GiMySkfAllTOQvXVMYfffff');

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
//$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
  print "No labels found.\n";
} else {
  print "Labels:\n";
  foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
    printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
  }
}
?>
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message
>   'Could not json decode the token' in
>   /home/[my domain]/public/GoogleAPI/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:179
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/[my domain]/public/GoogleAPI/src/Google/Client.php(215):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->setAccessToken('ya29.hwFcwk2M73...') #1
>   /home/[my domain]/public/labels.php(17):
>   Google_Client->setAccessToken('ya29.hwFcwk2M73...') #2 {main} thrown
>   in
>   /home/[my domain]/public/GoogleAPI/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php
>   on line 179

I'm sure I'm making this more difficult than it should be. I'm using the PHP example of showing a users labels, even though my final goal is to send emails.

Comment: Have you looked at Googles own PHP examples?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

Comment: Yes. At length. The example is the entire oauth process and just about returning labels. I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply that to my need where I already have the client's token (do I set that to $client somehow?) Also, looking for how to send the email from the client's gmail account and not having luck going from the labels example to actually sending mail...

Comment: User id refers to user's email address. You can check this link https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php for using token in the requests.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try using the email as the user ID, but still not clear how to create the request and where to put the client's token. I've reviewed that link you sent too. Just not clear how to format and utilize it in my PHP file. I'm sure it's very easy, I'm just not there. I'm reading up on REST APIs and hoping that will help. I would just love an example of sending an email using the Gmail API if I already have the client's email address and Oauth2 token...

Comment: You can check oauth play ground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ for sending sample requests with tokens.